# How badly do Fourier multipliers violate the product rule?

Tags: real-analysis, partial-differential-equations

Consider a differentiation operator that is not quite a derivative, eg.
$$\widehat{|D|f}(\xi)=|\xi|\hat f(\xi).$$
Do we have something like
$$|D|(fg)=f|D|g+g|D|f+\text{error}(f,g)$$
where the error doesn't take any derivatives and is maybe even smoothing? My inclination is to use a paraproduct but I can't get it to work out.

My intuition tells me something like this should be true but maybe only once we assume sufficient regularity of $f$ and $g$. I'm also interested if there are results like this for other Fourier multipliers, eg. $D|D|^{n-1}$.

Comment: Do you need some $L^p$ estimates?

Comment: Do you mean should I assume $L^p$ estimates on $f$ and $g$?

Comment: Do you need $L^p$ estimates on $\| D(fg)\|$?

Comment: The reason I ask is because the error could be absorbed.

Comment: I wouldn't mind simplifying things even further, for instance $f,g\in H^1(\mathbb R)$ so $D(fg)\in L^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have the Kato-Ponce inequality. Here's a reference paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/1303.5144v1.pdf.

Basically, you have

\begin{align}
\|D^s(fg)\|_{L^r} \lesssim \|D^sf\|_{L^{p_1}} \|g\|_{L^{q_1}}+\|f\|_{L^{p_2}} \|D^s g\|_{L^{q_2}}
\end{align}
where
\begin{align}
\frac{1}{r} = \frac{1}{p_i}+\frac{1}{q_i}.
\end{align}

Note: You have fractional derivative.

Comment: Thanks that's just what I was looking for.